# Scrapy - scraping comments skips the text after <br>

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am able to retrieve the text before the 
 tag but not the text after it.

This is the website that I am trying to scrape the comments from:
http://hamusoku.com/archives/9589071.html#comments

Starting from  some comments include the 
 tag which I think means that the user hit enter. Is there a way to get the text before and after the 
 tag as a single comment?

Here is a sample of the source code

```
<li="comment-body"> ==$0
    "
    愛の言葉も、この瞬間は辛い。"
    <br>
    "
    胸が締め付けられそうだ。"
```

This is my code:

```
import scrapy


class HamusoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hamuso'
    start_urls = ['http://hamusoku.com/archives/9589071.html#comments/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for com in response.css('li.comment-body'):
        item = {
        'comment': com.css('li::text').extract_first()
        }
        yield item
```

This is the output that I am getting in the shell:

```
{'comment': '\n\t\n\tかなしいなぁ'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\t海老蔵…つらいな'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\t海老蔵には頑張って欲しいな'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\t御冥福をお祈りします'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\t泣かすなや。'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\t海老蔵これからしっかりせなアカンぞ'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\t愛の言葉も、この瞬間は辛い。'}
{'comment': '\n\t\n\tただただ涙が止まらない会見だった'}
```

The last two comments both have a 
 tag and in both cases the second part of the comment is omitted.

I would really really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ran your spider and realised that when you `extraxt_first()`, you only get the first item or first comment the rest, which are after the `<br>` tags are unreacheable.

To solve this, use `extract()` this will return a list of all the comments in the `comment-body`

```
import scrapy

class HamusoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hamuso'
    start_urls = ['http://hamusoku.com/archives/9589071.html#comments/']
    def parse(self, response):
        for com in response.css('li.comment-body'):
            item = {'comment': com.css('li::text').extract()}
            yield item
```

the output I get for the last comment on your output is

```
{'comment': ['\n\t\n\tただただ涙が止まらない会見だった', '\n本当に短い人生だったけど豊かな人生だったのがわかる']}
{'comment': ['\n\t\n\t愛の言葉も、この瞬間は辛い。', '\n胸が締め付けられそうだ。']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're the best, I can't believe i spent 2 hours trying to fix that.